# C programming question on lookup table and array[char a] meaning

Tags: c

I came across this solution and I do not understand codes from line 25. Can someone explain to me line by line? Also, question on:

1. What does s2lut[c] get since c is a char?
2. Is there any meaning of using s2lut[256]? I get different output if I change the 256 to max(which I defined to be 100).

This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 100

int main() {
    void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);
    char s1[max] = "I am testing function that deletes character that matches characters in s2";
    char s2[max] = "ac";
    squeeze(s1, s2);
    printf("After deleting the characters in s2: %s \n", s1);
    return 0;
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    if (!s1[0] || !s2[0])
        return; /* Nothing to do if either string is empty */

    char s2lut[256], c;
    int i;
    int ri; /* Index of s1 to read char from */
    int wi; /* Index of s1 to write char to */

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        s2lut[i] = 0;

    i = 0;
    while (c = s2[i++])
        s2lut[c] = 1;

    ri = wi = 0;
    while (s1[ri])
    {
        if (s2lut[s1[ri++]])
            s1[wi] = s1[ri];
        else
            s1[++wi] = s1[ri];
    }

    s1[wi] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: In `if (temp < 300) recur_mul(temp);` you don't return anything and trigger undefined behaviour.

Comment: Here: `if (temp < 300) recur_mul(temp);` you're not returning the result, so that's probably the cause of your infinite loop.

Comment: If the compiler give you a warning about not returning a value, then you should enable more warnings.

Comment: Don’t put two questions in one post.  Please make a separate post for each question.

Comment: And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: _"sorry for asking 2 questions in one post but I do want to get my answer ASAP"_ The latter is not an excuse for the former.

Comment: Re "*What does s2lut[c] get since c is a char*", A `char` is number just like an `int` so, `s2lut[c]` gets the character `c` positions beyond `*s2lut`.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58770552/1) if you want to ask the first question

Comment: You do not need max. Let the compiler figure it out!

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) s2lut[i] = 0;` initializes all elements in `s2lut` zero. Now, if you are using the character (ASCII value) as the index in `s2lut[c] = 1;` woudln't looping over `s2lut` when you are done and checking if an element is `1` tell you that the ASCII character that corresponds to that array index appeared in `s2[]`? See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: `char s2lut[256] = {0};`  should zero the lot and therefore no need for the loop

Answer (score -1):

> I do not understand codes from line 25

I assume you're asking about this loop:

```
   while (c = s2[i++])
        s2lut[c] = 1;
```

It's equivalent to:

```
c = s2[i++];
while (c != 0) {
    s2lut[c] = 1;
    c = s2[i++];
}
```

So you see we've got two things going on.  The expression `c = s2[i++]`, as well as performing an assignment *has the value* of `c` after the assignment.  So you're rolling two steps into one.  Then you can treat any integer that's non-zero as a Boolean True, so so long as `c` is non-zero (ie not the termination character) the loop will continue.

I guess it looks a bit crazy if you're a beginner, but it's quite idiomatic for C.

> Is there any meaning of using s2lut[256]

In the declaration/definition, it has a clear meaning: please give me an array of 256 `chars`.

In use, it does not have a *valid* meaning, since the array has elements indexed 0 to 255, and you're not allowed to ask for element index 256 (the dreaded Undefined Behaviour).

> I change the 256 to max(which I defined to be 100).

Your code looks to be generating a lookup of target characters by assigning a marker to each possible value and setting that with each instance of that character seen in `s2`.

The general *assumption* (which if we're honest, is completely *fair* but not *correct*) is that a char will be one byte (8 bits) in size.  Thus is can have any of 256 possible values (`00000000` ... `01101101` ... `11111111`).  And lo!  We need 256 entries in `s2lut` (lut likely standing for "LookUp Table").

If you only make it 100 entries long, then any characters with a value of 100 or more will get slotted into memory you don't own and .... Undefined Behaviour!

Comment: I'm a little disappointed to get a down vote for this :(  Any comment about what is wrong?

Comment: How do the compiler locate the array position as normally we insert an integer like s2lut[2] which is the third element in the s2lut array so I'm kinda confused. Let's say c='a' then what does it mean for s2lut[a]?

Comment: In C, a character constant has the integer value corresponding to its ASCII value.  So `'a'` == 0x61 == 97 (decimal).  Hence `s2lut['a']` is equivalent to `s2lut[97]`.

Comment: @JohnKhor, has that answered your question, or do you still have further issues?  If you're all set, could you please accept my answer?

Comment: @JohnKhor, has that answered your question, or do you still have further issues? If you're all set, could you please accept my answer?